# Magento 2 Set Array Data in Controller and call in PHTML

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, controllers

**Controller**

```
public function execute()
    {

        $bags_result = array(   'height'=>$height,
                                'weight'=>$weight
                            );

        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Index')
                ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::calculation.phtml')
                ->setData('bags_result',$bags_result)
                ->toHtml();

        $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
        return $result;
    }
```

**Block File function**

```
public function getBagsResultData()
    {
        return $this->getBagsResult();
    }
```

**calculations.phtml**

```
<label><?php echo __('Height')?><span id="final-bmi-data"><?php echo $this->getBagsResultData('height')?></span></label>
<label><?php echo __('Weight')?><span id="final-bmi-data"><?php echo $this->getBagsResultData('weight')?></span></label>
```

Even if I change and use `$block->getBagsResultData()`; it gives the below error.

> Error: 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to
>   string conversion

How do I fetch and display array data set in **controller** using block or directly in phtml ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
public function getBagsResultData($var)
    {
        return $this->getBagsResult($var);
    }
```

or

```
 public function getBagsResultData($var)
    {
        $data = $this->getBagsResult();
        return $data[$var];
    }
```

In phtml you are passing the index but in method you output the array.

```
 <label><?php echo __('Height')?><span id="final-bmi-data"><?php echo $this->getBagsResultData('height')?></span></label>
<label><?php echo __('Weight')?><span id="final-bmi-data"><?php echo $this->getBagsResultData('weight')?></span></label>
```

Comment: It's a good way. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

In controller, you have to convert array in string and then send the data.

In phtml file, you have to explode the string.

**Controller**

```
public function execute()
    {


        $bags_height = 10;
        $bags_weight = 20;

        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Index')
                ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::calculation.phtml')
                ->setData('height',$bags_height)
                ->setData('weight',$bags_weight)
                ->toHtml();

        $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
        return $result;
    }
```

**Block File function**

```
public function getBagsHeight()
    {
        return $this->getHeight();
    }

    public function getBagsWeight()
    {
        return $this->getWeight();
    }
```

**calculations.phtml**

```
<label><?php echo __('Height')?><span id="final-bmi-data"><?php echo $block->getBagsHeight(); ?></span></label>
<label><?php echo __('Weight')?><span id="final-bmi-data"><?php echo $block->getBagsWeight(); ?></span></label>
```

Comment: We didn't implode twice. We imploded in controller and exploded in phtml file. check the answer.

Comment: But then it will give - `Notice: Undefined index` as we are converting it in array

Comment: comment your full error

Comment: The array generates like this - Array([0]=>11, [1]=>10). It gives index and not array key like height or weight

Comment: Why are you passing array in $bags_result ? set data seperately for both height and weight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66872/discussion-between-dinesh-yadav-and-vikram).